# What type of insect is this? Is it ant or something else?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I was sitting under morning sunshine when I saw this:

[image: img 1]
[image: img 2]
[image: img 3]

At first, I thought that it is a common Indian black ant. But it was moving much faster. Also, it seemed to have 2 (or probably more) eyes (sorry, couldn't take images as 'twas too fast). The most surprising part was when it leapt over the chair WITH A WEB! (just like a spider). Also, its mandibles(?) are much bigger than an ant's. Is it some kind of hybrid of ant and spider. I recently read that in some caves new varieties of spiders, which look like beetles (or maybe opposite) have been discovered. Is this related to them?

*Details:* I found it in Northern Plains, India. Its length is almost 1 cm (maybe bigger) and breadth is about 0.5 cm (actually slightly smaller than that).

Comment: This one is an ant,[Common Indian black ant](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50860/cannibalizing-behaviour-in-ants/50866#50866).Ant being an insect has 3 pairs of legs but this one his has 2 pairs,must have got it's body cut. The small projections at front are the antennae.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I see you found the other half :p. Cool find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a queer species. I thought it was an ant. But it is actually a **spider**.

These spiders belong to [Salticidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider) family,commonly called ant-mimicking spiders / jumping spiders.

> They are  Batesian mimics of ants, such as Sphecotypus in the Clubionidae.

They do not feed on their model organisms and keep them at an acceptable distance.

This one is from [Myrmarachne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrmarachne) sp. There are more than 20 species found in India.

[image]

Source:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_mimicry#Spiders)
- [Myrmarachne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrmarachne)

Comment: @another'Homosapien' If you are not an expert on the group, or can find extremely conclusive evidence that points to one specific species, you shouldn't push to add a specific species name. Species information on the internet is scattered at best, and you cannot expect to be able to identify every single species based on google searches and a couple of websites. There is no problem of leaving it at the family name or *Genus sp.*, if that is what is relatively certain.